# Is there a way to disable keyboard navigation in react-dropdown-tree-select?

Tags: react-dropdown-tree-select

We are using react-dropdown-tree-select, but we don't really need keyboard navigation, and the behavior where the last items are removed as you backspace past the beginning of the selection is undesirable in this application.  Is there a way to disable/suppress this?